# Is there any way in java to selectively escape few special characters

Tags: java, regex

I have a pattern stored in a text file and I am reading from file and using that pattern to match strings.

Example: `/abc/def[\d]/ghi`

Now I expect it should match with `/abc/def[1]/ghi`, `/abc/def[2]/ghi`

If I use Pattern.quote("/abc/def[\d]/ghi"), it will consider whole input as Literal, so only string with which it will match is "/abc/def[\d]/ghi"

So I have to save the pattern in file like `/abc/def\[\d\]/ghi`, where I am loosing the readability.

Is there any way to specifically escape few characters, like in my case I want '\d' to have a special meaning but do not want '[]' to have a special meaning.

Comment: There might be a problem for a simple solution: Assuming the match string `/abc[\d]/def[\d]/ghi` the first `[\d\]` should be treated as literal, whereas the second should be treated as character group. How you would know it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the required match, your pattern **must** look like

```
\[\d\]
```

in the end. But to make things more readable, consider using methods to build such pattern expressions instead of hardcoding them as literal, like:

```
String encloseInSquareBrackets(String pattern) {
  return "\[" + pattern + "]";
}

...
String pattern = "/abc/def" + encloseInSquareBrackets("\d")+ "/ghi";
```

for example. Yes, that means more text to read, but assuming you spent some time to come up with good method names, this keeps your pattern definitions easier to read/understand.

One could even go one step further and create some "RegexBuilder" class that provides a nice set of such kind of methods; allowing for a fluent interface.

Answer (score 1):

Escape the brackets:

```
/abc/def\[\d\]/ghi
```

UPDATE:

To avoid escaping the brackets in the input file, you can escape them after reading them:

```
public String escapeSquareBrackets(String e) {
    return e.replaceAll("([\\[\\]])", "\\$1");
}
```

Comment: I gave that answer, too. Until I realized that he already knows that. He finds that pattern hard to read and is asking if it can be expressed in other ways.

Comment: And err, he used the java tag. Your source code doesn't look at all like java.

Comment: I would rename the method - it doesn't escape everything - it just escapes  square brackets. And the kinda worse part - the method can be dangerous. You have to remember to **never** use it with patterns that contain "real groups". Upvoted anyway.

Comment: Well, sometimes reputation earning is a hard and serious business ;-)